# Visual Studio Team Services with SharePoint online

Tags: office365, azure-devops

Is it possible to integrate my SharePoint online site (`xxx.sharepoint.com`) with Visual Studio Team Services (`xxx.visualstudio.com`)?  I would like to use some web parts in SharePoint page to track Work items on VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

No. For reporting in VSTS, you can use the built in dashboard capabilities or hook Power BI up to your VSTS instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Team Services can integrate with Office 365 enables you to keep your group informed of important activities that are happening in your team project.

Configure some or all of these events to appear in your team's Office 365 Group:

- Build completed
- Code pushed
- Work item created, updated, or commented on

Check: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-o365